# React hooks - dependencies rerun hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I keep struggling with the same issue with React Hooks. The dependency array.
I have many hooks that should trigger and handle different events.
For instance:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const doSomethingWith = (notification: Notifications.Notification) => {
    ...
    setUser({ notifications: badgeCount });
  };

  notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(
    (notification) => {
      if (user) {
        doSomethingWith(notification);
      }
    }
  );

  return () => {
    Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener);
  };
}, [setExpoPushToken, setUser, user]);
```

In this simplified code, you can see that I track notifications and when I get it, I use the data in the notification and update the user object with it.

However, this whole thing will run whenever the user is updated. Like, if I update the user first name - the notification hook will run. That makes little sense to me. It forces me to add if statements inside these hook functions which is a waste and makes my code ugly.

What am I missing? How do I handle this better?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "It forces me to add if statements inside these hook functions which is a waste and makes my code ugly." What happens if you don't use the if statement?

Comment: You can create a useEffect per dependency, that useEffect only will run if that dependency changes.
Since you've got one big useEffect with multiple dependencies, it will run if any of these dependencies changes (that's why it runs every time the user state changes)

Comment: @kimobrian254 you can see a `if(user)...` in my code. In here, I am making sure I actually have a user before running the doSomethingWith. Another if statement could be `if(user.hasCookies && Cookies === 'yummy' && ...`

Comment: @CelsoWellington In the effect I wrote there are only three dependencies. And I really only add them because I need to update the user with the data. I don't want it to run when the user is updated OUTSIDE of this hook. I don't want to listen to notifications AGAIN whenever the `user` changes. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense. Well, I suggest you to move the notifications to a separated state from the user and create an useEffect just for it because: when the user changes their name, for example, and you escape your notification useEffect, you won't listen for notifications anymore because of the previous cleanup, so, you would need to add it again. That's why I'm suggesting you to move it to a separated state and use that state as a dependency instead of using the user state :)

Comment: Thanks @CelsoWellington indeed, what I ended up doing was setting the "notification" state when one arrived and I created a useState which runs whenever a new notification is set. That useEffect also has the user and setUser as dependencies because it handles the rest of the logic that has to do with saving data from the notification in the user state object. Did I get it right? Is that how you'd handle it?